# Adding support to the new Rupee symbol to iTextPDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, itext

My project is related to a billing application and I am using the iTextPdf library for PDF file generation. However my requirement is to display the new Rupee symbol in the PDF generated by iTextPdf, instead of "Rs.".

I know that following Unicode `\u20B9` is for the new Rupee symbol. I am using the following code for formatting:

```
String formater(String a) {
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 000");
  return formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(a));
}
```

But the generated PDF file does not show any Rupee symbol. So how can I use that with the iTextPdf library? Is there any additional font required to be merged with the library itself?

Comment: the pdf is not supporting the special character. try changing the character set of PDF to UTF-8

Comment: I have set charset of my project to UTF-8 in NetBeans IDE, Is there anything additional that I need to do for setting charset, Please let me know.

Comment: If you want help concerning iText use, you had better supply your code using iText, in this case especially concerning the font selection. @Naveen provided some general references. If that doesn't help, please provide relevant code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mkl, Naveen for the help.

Hope this can help someone, I did the following for this:

Step 1: Downloaded Font that has Rupee Symbol Unicode (for this I updated my windows ([Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898) and got the arial font with rupee symbol)

Step 2: Using iText I created the embedded base font with IDENTITY_H encoding:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(this.getClass().getResource("arial.ttf").toString(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(baseFont);
```

Now the pdf generated has the new rupee symbol.

Answer (score 0):

changing in IDE is not the issue.
Your iTextPDF will be writing content into PDF in a particular character set. that controls if the data is shown properly or not.

you can try these 2 links

[SO question for that contain how to check character set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3753961/648157)

[iTextPdf site for how to correct character set](http://www.itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11)